# Routes on Rails buttons don't work... But they do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have a very strange problem. I have an accordion menu inside a Rails app. I have a set of links inside the menu that go to respective "posts." This works fine, except I need the area AROUND the link to be clickable, not just the text. So I switched them to buttons. Not rocket science. Everything works except for a strange issue. When I click on the button, I get the routing error page. It says:

```
No route matches [POST] "/posts/14"
```

For the route in the URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/posts/14
```

Now, what is very, very strange is if I try to resend the URL request... the page loads. It only gets stopped when I use the button. But if I reload the page from the routing error page, I get the post. What???

Here is a section of my dropdown menu. The first section, "Beginner," is an example of my new button layout. It does not work unless I reload the error page. The second section, "Strumming" is the old link layout. It works the way it should:

```
<button class="accordion">Beginner</button> 
<div class="panel">
    <% if @beginner.empty? %> 
        <p class="sidebar_lesson"><i>No lessons available</i></p>
    <% else %> 
        <% @beginner.each do |p| %> 
            <%= button_to p.title, post_path(p), class: 'sidebar_lesson' %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %> 
</div>
<button class="accordion">Strumming</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <% if @strumming.empty? %> 
            <p class="sidebar_lesson"><i>No lessons available</i></p>
        <% else %>
            <% @strumming.each do |p| %> 
                <p class='sidebar_lesson'><%= link_to p.title, post_path(p) %></p>
            <% end %>
        <% end %> 
    </div>
```

Here are my routes, which include the route I am requesting:

```
       new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       users/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       users/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      users/sessions#destroy
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
       user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                     POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
   user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                     PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                     DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                     POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
               posts GET    /posts(.:format)               posts#index
                     POST   /posts(.:format)               posts#create
            new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)           posts#new
           edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)      posts#edit
                post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#show
                     PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#update
                     PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#update
                     DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#destroy
                root GET    /                              posts#index
```

Can someone let me know what is going on here? I am very confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

button_to uses the HTTP POST method by default https://cardoni.net/rails-button-to-vs-link-to-url-helpers/

What you want is to make your button_to fire a GET request to your route. You do this by specifying a method like so

```
    <% @beginner.each do |p| %> 
        <%= button_to p.title, post_path(p), method: :get, class: 'sidebar_lesson' %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: That's the answer. I didn't know that. Thank you!